# I have an existing SQLite database but failed to use it with my app

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I have read several tutorial about my problem for example [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database) there no one make me clear about the whole procedure. Everyone told about the DataBaseHelper class but no one did showed how to implement with MainActivity.  Also what cursor should we use to pull the data and keep the those data in a String each column.

Here is my DataBaseHelper.java code but it doesnot copy the data into my app.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window
    //destination path (location) of our database on device
    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static String DB_NAME ="SBLdata.db";// Database name
    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
            DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        }
        else
        {
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        }
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        //If database not exists copy it from the assets

        boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
        if(!mDataBaseExist)
        {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();
            try
            {
                //Copy the database from assests
                copyDataBase();
                //Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
            }
            catch (IOException mIOException)
            {
                throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
            }
        }
    }
    //Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name
    private boolean checkDataBase()
    {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    //Copy the database from assets
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
        {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }

    //Open the database, so we can query it
    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException
    {
        String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
       // Log.v("mPath", mPath);
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);

        return mDataBase != null;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close()
    {
        if(mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

What should add on my MainActivity.java ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    DataBaseHelper SBLdataCreate;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "SBLdata.db";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DataBaseHelper dbOpenHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this, DB_NAME);
        database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? what isn't working?

Comment: I think you might missed dbOpenHelper.createDataBase()

Comment: After Running the app in my emulator no database create

Comment: See my second comment

Comment: Yes You are right it works :P

Comment: Can you mark the answer?

Comment: Can you help me to pull the data from database ? My database has 4 column and I need them as a listview ?

Comment: You should ask another question for this, and I will try and answer there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create the database before attempting to open it and make a query.
In your code I don't see that you're creating the DB prior to opening it.

For example:

```
    DataBaseHelper dbOpenHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this, DB_NAME);
    dbOpenHelper.createDataBase()
    database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();
```

Comment: your method is correct but your should use try---catch

Comment: This is not relevant to the question, and actually the code you posted is quite harmfull in my opinion

Comment: Just to clarify - if dbOpenHelper.openDataBase() is depending on dbOpenHelper.createDataBase() it should be in the same try clause.

Comment: @UdiI could you please answer my another question ? I am posting it ...Please

Comment: Can you add a link to the new question?

Comment: :( does not allow me to post another question. May I post it my blog and give you the link ?

Comment: Why can't you post a question?

Comment: @UdiI  here is the [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824558/how-to-pull-data-from-database-and-view-them-as-a-listview)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a better way this might be work for you :)**

```
DataBaseHelper dbOpenHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this, DB_NAME);

  try {
    database = dbOpenHelper.createDataBase();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();
```

Comment: How is it better? can you please explain?

Comment: When I use @Udi I  code it show a red underline and ask me to add try catch and rupom KHondaker do exacly that what I need ......Thanks Both of you :P

Comment: You shouldn't add try catch this way. Did you stop to think what will happen if the code inside your try will fail? what then will happen in dbOpenHelper.createDataBase()?

Comment: No, Sorry ! I am very new in android. If I am wrong please forgive me :)