# How to pull data from database and view them as a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I am using a custom list adapter for my ListView. My each list item has 4 items. which are come from a listArray.

Here is the code which pull the list items from List Array.

```
   import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;



import com.rupomkhondaker.sonalibank.adapter.PhoneListAdapter;
import com.rupomkhondaker.sonalibank.model.ContactItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class GMOFragment extends Fragment {
    public GMOFragment(){}


    private boolean database;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "SBLdata.db";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gmo, container, false);

        final ArrayList<ContactItem> listData = getListData();

        final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gmolistView);
        listView.setAdapter(new PhoneListAdapter(getActivity(), listData));


        DataBaseHelper dataOpen = new DataBaseHelper((MainActivity) getActivity(), DB_NAME);
        //Trying to open the DataBase
        database = dataOpen.openDataBase();



        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                ContactItem newsData = (ContactItem) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ContactDetail.class);

                intent.putExtra("DATA_KEY", newsData);

                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

        return rootView;
    }

  private ArrayList<ContactItem> getListData() {
        ArrayList<ContactItem> listMockData = new ArrayList<ContactItem>();


       String sqlQuery = "select BR_NAME,PHONE,MOBILE,EMAIL from SBL_Contact";
       Cursor contactsCursor = database.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);

       ContactItem newsData = null;

      while (contactsCursor.moveToNext()) {
          newsData = new ContactItem();
          newsData.setName(contactsCursor.getString(0));
          newsData.setPhone(contactsCursor.getString(1));
          newsData.setMobile(contactsCursor.getString(2));
          newsData.setEmail(contactsCursor.getString(3));

          listMockData.add(newsData);
      }
        return listMockData;
    }

}
```

But Now I have created the same list in my SBLdata (databse_name) in SBL_Contact (table name)  Column 1.NAME, 2.PHONE, 3.MOBILE , 4.EMAIL

Now please help me to pull the data and set them to getListData()

Comment: You want to get the data from the DB instead of R.array?

Comment: yes you are right. my above code works with R.array  perfect but I need to use it with the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a sql query e.g.:

```
String sqlQuery = "select name,phone,mobile,email from SBL_Contact";
```

Then use it with a cursor to get the results:

```
Cursor contactsCursor = database.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);
```

and then iterate through your cursor:

```
ContactItem newsData = null;

while (contactsCursor.moveToNext()) {
       newsData = new ContactItem();
       newsData.setName(contactsCursor.getString(0));
       newsData.setPhone(contactsCursor.getString(1));
       newsData.setMobile(contactsCursor.getString(2));
       newsData.setEmail(contactsCursor.getString(3));

       listMockData.add(newsData);
    }
```

Comment: in `Cursor contactsCursor = database.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);` why rawQuery show a red underline ?

Comment: What's the message you're getting?

Comment: When I mouse hover it " Cannot resolved method rawQuery(........." something like this

Comment: Do you have the imports needed?

Comment: Just post your code if possible, it would be much easier that way

Comment: Try adding import android.database.Cursor;

Comment: I'm looking into it, but I did notice you didn't create the DB again, before you attempt to open it.

Comment: Also import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

Comment: The query should be invoked on the Database instance. In your code database is a boolean. Please update your code so it will use it accordingly.

Comment: I failed can you help me to update my code and how it should look like?

Comment: Change your SQLiteOpenHelper code so you'll get a reference to your DB.
   //Open the database, so we can query it
    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException
    {
        String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);

        return mDataBase;
    }